# Are wasps attracted to UV light emissions?

Tags: entomology, behaviour

I remember seeing a documentary where it was shown that bees and wasps are attracted to UV components of a flower colour (please correct me if I am wrong).

Does this mean that they could be attracted by neon lights (that I suspect are emitting also in the UV part of the spectrum)?

I am asking because I have neon lights in my office and if I have the lights on I can't open the window, or a wasp will almost immediately enter the office. I've experimented a bit, and turning off the light makes the wasp go out rather quickly, hence my hypothesis.

I am located in Europe, if that makes a difference for the species involved. Outside the window we have some tall trees, so we keep some lights on even when the sun is out.